# AttributeError: module 'tqdm' has no attribute 'auto'

Tags: python, pytorch, tqdm, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to run a git repo called Spacetimeformer and I am getting this error while training a program

```
lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\functional\text\bert.py", line 247, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tqdm' has no attribute 'auto'
```

The code looks like this:

```
def _get_progress_bar(dataloader: DataLoader, verbose: bool = False) -> Union[DataLoader, tqdm.auto.tqdm]:
    """Helper function returning either the dataloader itself when `verbose = False`, or it wraps the dataloader with
    `tqdm.auto.tqdm`, when `verbose = True` to display a progress bar during the embbeddings calculation."""
    return tqdm.auto.tqdm(dataloader) if verbose else dataloader
```

I could not get any help online nor has the author of the repo answered this question.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a torchmetrics bug - it only imports `tqdm` when it needs to import `tqdm.auto`. You should [file a bug report](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/torchmetrics/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tqdm.auto.tqdm(dataloader)` with `tqdm.tqdm(dataloader)`.